# Handling errors in Python scripts

Tags: python, xml, wordpress

Using [pyblog.py](http://code.google.com/p/python-blogger/source/browse/trunk/pyblog.py?spec=svn4&r=4), I got the following error, which I then tried to more gracefully handle:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~1\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\mmorisy\Desktop\My Dropbox\python\betterblogmaster.py", line 11, in <module>
    date = blogurl.get_recent_posts(1)[0]['dateCreated']
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\mmorisy\Desktop\My Dropbox\python\pyblog.py", line 129, in get_recent_posts
    return self.execute('metaWeblog.getRecentPosts', blogid, self.username, self.password, numposts)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\mmorisy\Desktop\My Dropbox\python\pyblog.py", line 93, in execute
    raise BlogError(fault.faultString)
BlogError: XML-RPC services are disabled on this blog.  An admin user can enable them at http://example.com/blogname/wp-admin/options-writing.php
>>>
```

So I tried the following code to without crashing the script:

```
for blog in bloglist:
    try:
        blogurl = pyblog.WordPress('http://example.com' + blog + 'xmlrpc.php', 'admin', 'laxbro24')
        date = blogurl.get_recent_posts(1)[0]['dateCreated']
        print blog + ', ' + str(date.timetuple().tm_mon) + '/' + str(date.timetuple().tm_mday) + '/' + str(date.timetuple().tm_year)
    except BlogError:
        print "Oops! The blog at " + blogurl + " is not configured properly."
```

Only to get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\SITE-P~1\PYTHON~1\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\mmorisy\Desktop\My Dropbox\python\betterblogmaster.py", line 13, in <module>
    except BlogError:
NameError: name 'BlogError' is not defined
```

Isn't the name blog error defined by PyBlog, since that's where I got that name in the first place? Am I using "except" wrong? Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is using BlogError, but you have not imported BlogError into your namespace to reference. You instead want to be using pyblog.BlogError:

```
for blog in bloglist:
    try:
        blogurl = pyblog.WordPress('http://example.com' + blog + 'xmlrpc.php', 'admin', 'laxbro24')
        date = blogurl.get_recent_posts(1)[0]['dateCreated']
        print blog + ', ' + str(date.timetuple().tm_mon) + '/' + str(date.timetuple().tm_mday) + '/' + str(date.timetuple().tm_year)
    except pyblog.BlogError:
        print "Oops! The blog at " + blogurl + " is not configured properly."
```

Remember that exceptions follow the same rules of scoping that any python object does.

Comment: Thanks, I really need to brush up on my scoping. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your `except` is syntactically correct. And yet it fails because you haven't explicitly imported the `BlogError` exception class into your program's namespace.

To fix this explicitly import the `BlogError` class. For e.g.

```
from pyblog import BlogError
try:
    ...
except BlogError:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

the code will be

```
 from pyblog import BlogError
```